React Instantsearch with Transliteration: Incorrect Intermediate Results During Typing
I'm building a search component using React InstantSearch that includes Sanskrit transliteration using the @indic-transliteration/sanscript library.
The transliteration happens on each keystroke, which causes incorrect intermediate results.
Current Behavior
When typing "राम" (rāma):

Type "r" → converts to "र्"
Type "a" → converts to "र्अ"
Instead of building up to the correct syllable "रा"

import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useInstantSearch, useSearchBox, UseSearchBoxProps } from 'react-instantsearch';
import Sanscript from '@indic-transliteration/sanscript';

export const SearchBar = (props: UseSearchBoxProps) => {
    const { query, refine } = useSearchBox(props);
    const { status } = useInstantSearch();
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(query);
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    
    function setQuery(newQuery: string) {
        console.log("newquery", newQuery)
        const transliteratedText = Sanscript.t(newQuery, 'itrans', 'devanagari');
        setInputValue(transliteratedText);
        refine(transliteratedText);
        console.log("transliteratedText", transliteratedText)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form action="" role="search" noValidate>
                <input
                    ref={inputRef}
                    value={inputValue}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setQuery(event.currentTarget.value);
                    }}
                    // ... other props
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

Console Output
newquery r
transliteratedText र्
newquery र्a
transliteratedText र्अ

How can i make this work correctly with React InstantSearch by handling this transliteration correctly?
